# How to re-fire a click element containing setTimeout callbacks and animations

Tags: javascript, click, frontend, settimeout, addeventlistener

In the below example, I've managed to highlight a clicked div element and its parents, then make them white in the same order with a little delay between each (please try out the snippet).

What I'm trying to add is that **if user clicks one of the div elements again before the whole animation(highlighting and turning into white, basically returning to the initial state) ends, it should restart the animation again from the div element clicked.** In other words, every new click during animation restarts it. How do I achieve this? I've tried count approach but I'm not exactly sure to what parameter I should link it. Somehow I need to stop setTimeout functions and make divs white within the click event when another click comes before animation ends.

Sorry if it is too confusing, actually pretty understandable. Please ask me if you're lost. Thanks in advance.

Link of the actual demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-https-14m6c?file=/src/index.js

```js
const allDivElements = document.querySelectorAll("div");

let timeout = 300;
allDivElements.forEach((div) => {
  div.addEventListener("click", function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      changeBg(this, true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        changeBg(this, false);
        timeout = 300;
      }, timeout);
    }, timeout);
    timeout += 300;
  });
});

function changeBg(div, phase) {
  if (phase) div.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
  else div.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
}

// Please make each div clickable programmatically, considering UX
// 1 - Log the id of the clicked div.
// 2 - make clicked div and parents highlighted by changing background color,
//     respectively with a small delay
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css" />
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="1">
      1
      <div id="2">
        2
        <div id="3">
          3
          <div id="4">
            4
            <div id="5">
              5
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store all the ids that setTimeout returns, and then clear them when another user click occurs. If this new click happens before all the animation was finished, then it will stop them, but if it comes after the animations finished, then it does nothing, which is what you want

e.g.

```
let pendingAnimations = [];

allDivElements.forEach((div) => {
  div.addEventListener("click", function () {
    pendingAnimations.forEach(id => clearTimeout(id));
    pendingAnimations = [];

    const id1 = setTimeout(() => {
      changeBg(this, true);

      const id2 = setTimeout(() => {
        changeBg(this, false);
        timeout = 300;
      }, timeout);

      pendingAnimations.push(id2);
    }, timeout);

    pendingAnimations.push(id1);
    timeout += 300;
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, it will not work since timeout is reset in each step of the forEach loop. Like, in the first iteration, it fills the pendingAnimations array for just a div animation, then it immediately removes it in the second iteration, and like so. It is like, each animation is created and immediately removed afterwards. That is the real problem actually. How am I supposed to remove it in a loop? Should I stick to the ES5-ES6 features?